# hybrid app built with ionic crashes on android but not ios

Tags: java, javascript, android, angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm building an app using the Ionic framework and AngularJS. When I run ionic run android the app installs and then crashes on my device. I ran logcat to watch the crash happen and it was throwing `java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid long: ""`

Interestingly the app runs on iOS perfectly fine, it only crashes on android.
Anywho know what I should be looking for to fix this? I'm having a hard time trying to find the issue as the code is in javascript and html so I can't find where the invalid long is.

full log cat of the exception

```
E/AndroidRuntime( 3057): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime( 3057): Process: com.gravityfusion.findmydriver, PID: 3057
E/AndroidRuntime( 3057): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.gravityfusion.findmydriver/com.gravityfusion.findmydriver.CordovaApp}: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid long: ""
E/AndroidRuntime( 3057):        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2298)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3057):        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3057):        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3057):        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3057):        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3057):        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3057):        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3057):        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3057):        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3057):        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3057):        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3057): Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid long: ""
E/AndroidRuntime( 3057):        at java.lang.Long.invalidLong(Long.java:124)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3057):        at java.lang.Long.decode(Long.java:142)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3057):        at org.apache.cordova.CordovaPreferences.copyIntoIntentExtras(CordovaPreferences.java:139)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3057):        at org.apache.cordova.CordovaActivity.loadConfig(CordovaActivity.java:240)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3057):        at org.apache.cordova.CordovaActivity.onCreate(CordovaActivity.java:207)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3057):        at com.gravityfusion.findmydriver.CordovaApp.onCreate(CordovaApp.java:30)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3057):        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5933)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3057):        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3057):        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2251)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3057):        ... 10 more
```

~edit
I can build the app with no errors or warnings using `ionic build android`.
I can install the app on my device.
When I go to run it, it instantly crashes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because of this line in the error

```
at org.apache.cordova.CordovaPreferences.copyIntoIntentExtras(CordovaPreferences.java:139)
```

I had a look in the config.xml file where the preferences are entered. I found several errors in the preferences that iOS defaults but android doesn't like `<preference name="BackgroundColor" value="0xffffffff"/>` which was `<preference name="BackgroundColor" value=""/>`